# Отображение всех авторизованных пользователей и/или последнего зарегистрированного

Tags: php, auth

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как сделать вывод на экран всех авторизованных пользователей на данный момент(был такой блок на сервисе ucoz)? Или хотя бы их кол-во. Предполагаю, что нужно в бд, в таблицу user добавить поле вроде state, boolean типа, и во время авторизации записывать true, а вовремя выхода - false, а потом сделать выборку по этому полю и выводить либо имена пользователей, либо count. На данный момент авторизация сделана на сессиях, может с ними что-то придумать можно? Последнего авторизованного пользователя предполагаю искать по максимальному id.
Безопасно ли использовать мой способ и будет ли он работать? Или может есть что-либо проще/сложнее, но правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создай отдельное поле для хранения данных типа `datetime`.
2. При каждом запросе от авторизованного пользователя записывай туда текущее время.
3. Делай выборку из БД полей, где значение этого параметра отличается от текущего на не более чем 10 (или сколько угодно минут).
4. Готово.

Фрагмент запроса на пользователей онлайн из БД: `(now() - lastOnline) < " . время_в_секундах . "`.

По id не выйдет, ты просто выведешь самого нового пользователя сайта, который *возможно (а может и нет)* сейчас в сети.

Пользователи не выходят из профилей, в большинстве своём, и при реализации в виде boolean-ов будут "висеть" в списке "кто онлайн?" всё время.

Answer (score 0):

> Последнего авторизованного пользователя предполагаю искать по максимальному id

Не в коем случае только по дате и времени.

Comment: А если не тяжело - не подскажете почему?

Comment: @abrgpro, потому что у поля id иная семантика, и оно не обязано монотонно возрастать